# pdflatex cannot find file but kpsewhich does

Tags: pdftex, texlive, environment-variables, kpathsea

I have a `header.tex` file sitting in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/` and I tried using `\input` in another `.tex` file in some other directory. Note that `kpsewhich` is able to find `header.tex`, printing its full path, and I have also applied `texhash` on my `$TEXMFHOME` directory.

However, `pdflatex` does not seem to be able to locate the file.

I have tried going through both the documentation for `kpathsea` and `pdflatex` for pointers. The `pdflatex` states that `$TEXINPUTS` is the search path for `\input` files. And so I appended `$TEXMFHOME` to that environment, which I believe I should not need to, but alas.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually one should not apply `texhash` to `$TEXMFHOME` nor use `$TEXINPUTS`.

Comment: What's the exact text of the error message you get and what's the minimal code you try compiling to get that message?

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I do understand that and I had a similar setup in another system, and I did not have to fiddle with `texhash` and `$TEXINPUTS`. But I had to give them a try to see if it leads me anywhere.

Comment: @cfr I will add that to my original post.

Comment: Actually, I have found the root of my problem and thus my solution. Can I have some advice on how I should close this thread? Should I provide my solution as an answer, or should I just add it to the original post?

Comment: It depends a bit on what the solution is. If your question is a duplicate, we can close it with a link to the duplicate. If the problem is due to something like a typo, we'd usually just close it with some not-quite-fitting-reason-as-we-can-only-pick-from-multiple-choice. Otherwise, you should answer the question. You shouldn't put your answer in the question.

Comment: don't put the answer in the question, if you think the answer may be of use to others, post a self answer, or if it's just a typo, you could delete the question.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the advice. I have posted a self answer, since I could not find a duplicate, nor do I believe that my problem was a typo. I can't be certain, but hopefully it might help throw in some light for those that come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I failed to mention that I was using `texliveonfly`, which is a my mistake when asking my question. To run `texliveonfly`, I need `sudo` so that `texliveonfly` can install missing packages, just as you would need `sudo` rights to install packages via `tlmgr` if your system is set up that way.

The problem lies in the fact that the environment that the task is in when you run as `sudo` is different from your user environment. In the case of when I am running as `sudo`, `$TEXMFHOME` does not point to any directory, and hence it could not find my files.

Now I can either set up a `$TEXMFHOME` for root, or use `$TEXMFLOCAL` instead. I went with the later and that solved my problem.

Comment: I have to say that the idea of compiling with root privileges fills sends a chill down my spine. I won't even run `tlmgr` with root privileges or `install-tl`. Compiling as root cannot possibly be considered safe, surely, do the `texliveonfly` developers seriously recommend this?

Comment: It depends on the structure of how `tlmgr` was installed. If you require `sudo` to install packages with `tlmgr`, then `texliveonfly` can only ask for the same, which is why I mentioned that "if your system is set up that way".

Comment: But, since people standardly do install that way, that is the standard case. I'm amazed anybody would even consider using it this way.